# CSS Flexbox - Two columns with 'content wrap under' conundrum

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

Hugely frustrated that I've had to admit defeat on this one, just when I thought I had flexbox grokked! Apologies for the strange description but the issue is easier shown that described.

**What I need:**
All four labelled divs (title, left, right, under-left) must all reside within a common container. Left and Right cols take up half the space each, but UNDER-LEFT must tuck under LEFT regardless of the height of RIGHT.

[image: what i want]

**What I've got:** At present as I increase the height of RIGHT it is pushing UNDER-LEFT down with it :(

[image]

**My Code So Far**

```
<style>
#container {    
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;  
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 250px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
#under-left {   
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="heading">
        <p>title</p>
    </div>

    <div id="left">
        <p>LEFT height 250, basis 50%</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <p>RIGHT, basis 50%</p>
    </div>

    <div id="under-left">
    <p>UNDER-LEFT</p>
    </div>  

</div>
</body>
```

**What I've tried:**
To be honest I'm at a total loss. I have tried floating elements but of course flex ignores floats. I don't know what else to try, it's not laziness as it took me about 25 minutes to create this post. I have searched for other answers on SO (such as [CSS Flex Box Layout: full-width row and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160839/css-flex-box-layout-full-width-row-and-columns)) but none feature the wrap-under element issue.

Please be kind!

Comment: Flexbox can do this is the height of the left side is known, alternatively, the simplest method is to wrap the left side divs in a container of their own. Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: The point being, you are trying to force flexbox to do something it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, maybe wasn't clear that wrapping left DIVS in another container is not acceptable here, the reason is that I need to do some flexbox element ORDER changes for other viewports that would become problematic.

Comment: Can you post how that should look like, on other viewport's

Comment: @LGSon, on mobile I'm simply going to have all blocks width 100% so there is not much to show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this to use `flexbox` (needed a markup change)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#left {
  flex: 1;
}
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
#left-top {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
#left-bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="heading">
    <p>title</p>
  </div>

  <div id="left">
    <div id="left-top">
      LEFT height 250, basis 50%
    </div>
    
    <div id="left-bottom">
      UNDER-LEFT
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    RIGHT, basis 50%
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Update based on comment not being able to wrap the left `div`'s

*Note, this might be doable with `flexbox` and non wrapped `div`s, though I need to know how that layout should look like.*

Here is a floated version, which can use `flexbox` on smaller screens using `@media` query to reorder the elements visually.

To make the `under-left` always stay under the `left` regardless of the `right`'s height, you need to make them wider than the `right` (here 1px), have the left one's floated `left`, the right floated `right`

Sample, `right` lower

```css
#container {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
}
#under-left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="heading">
    <p>title</p>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <p>RIGHT, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="left">
    <p>LEFT height 250, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="under-left">
    <p>UNDER-LEFT</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Sample, `right` higher

```css
#container {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
}
#under-left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="heading">
    <p>title</p>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <p>RIGHT, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="left">
    <p>LEFT height 250, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="under-left">
    <p>UNDER-LEFT</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Update 2 based on yet another comment

Here is a floated version combined with `flexbox` and `@media` query, that will make them in the right order/size on smaller screens

```css
#container {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
}
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}
#right {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 1px);
}
#under-left {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #left,
  #under-left,
  #right {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  #right {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="heading">
    <p>title</p>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <p>RIGHT, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="left">
    <p>LEFT height 250, basis 50%</p>
  </div>

  <div id="under-left">
    <p>UNDER-LEFT</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, this has saved my butt! It works.